# CPQ Quote Document: formatting difference between preview and generated / saved PDF

Tags: pdf, cpq

Generating a CPQ Quote Document I get differently rendered PDFs, depending on whether I look at them via Preview Document or Generate Document and then save. The main issue is, generated & saved documents are all in bold text, whereas the template defines bold and non-bold texts. It seems there is also a different font used (but I'm not an expert on font faces, so it might just be the bold text).

Preview-generated document:

[image]

Generate & Save:

[image]

The style of each column is set to

[image]

Yes, there is only one template. Any idea what could be the reason for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh dear, there is no issue in creating the respective PDFs.

With document preview, a PDF file is generated and then left to the browser to render it.

If you click on a saved PDF, Salesforce renders a preview image. This preview image is not rendered correctly, looking like boldness looks the same.

Comment: Faced the same issue, isn't this something which should be raised as a bug with SF?